# Create a custom google maps with images taken from my mobile

Tags: android, image, google-maps

I am trying to create a map with locations marked with images. Users should be able to upload images and mark the locations using the gps co-ords in the images.

Any idea how to do it using google maps?

Comment: You can use a custom image for the location pin, you need to get a hold on MarkerOptions and use the method called icon(). Hope this helps

Comment: I saw the marker option. But is something along these lines possible-take a photo and upload it your custom maps where it gets placed using its geo tags?

Comment: In your main activity, you could start the camera using intent, see http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html, and once you got the picture back you can use the LocationManager to get the GPS coordinates, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html .

After this, it's just a matter of creating the appropriate marker and displaying it on the map. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man. Finally I settled on approaching it like that. I may have to host the gps and picture on my server though :)

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following conclusion after reading through google documentation.

All the information - the marker and image needs to be stored on your server. Google doesn't let users to host map data on their server. So if you have a server, you can save the geo lcoations and the uploaded image on it. When needed load those info when they are needed from the sever.